# Need help identifying a movie with struggling werewolf protagonist

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched a movie around 2005, the name of which I don't remember, and haven't been able to find the movie since. I was quite young when I watched it, so I have very few details about it. The details I remember are:

- The main character turns into a werewolf, and struggles to contain it
- A portal to either a hidden place or another world exists in a large painting that's missing a corner or a piece, and the main characters find and fix the painting
- The girlfriend of the main character dies at the end of the movie (I believe the main character couldn't refrain from becoming a werewolf while fighting the villain and accidentally mortally wounded her)

Comment: I know, it's not letting me for another 6 minutes. I assume it's because of how shortly it was answered or a client-side fault in my app.

Comment: Yes, there is a time limit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That would be [Van Helsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Helsing_(film)).

[image]

It stars Hugh Jackman as a monster hunter, overemoting by someone claiming to feel nothing, and a wonderful Frankenstein’s Monster.

Comment: Wow, asked and answered before I could even look at it.

Comment: "Why don't you go ahead and grab it?" "If there's one thing I've learned, it's never to stick your hand into a viscous material." My favorite line from that movie. :)

Comment: I added a poster to your answer. That should help people who come across this answer recognize the movie.

Comment: Wolverine : Origins : Origins